# Ansible module to filter file content

Tags: ansible

Is there some file module that would allow to read file, filter its content and store changed file in one task? Something like

```yaml
- shell: cat /path/file.txt
  register: file_content
- copy:
    content: "{{ file_content.stdout | from_json | to_nice_json(indent=4) }}"
    dest: "/path/file.txt"
```

but in single task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You may [write your own module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules.html), or use the shell command with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
- shell: cat /path/file.txt | jq '.' --indent 4 > /path/file.txt
```